# ¿Cómo traer el último registro de la tabla relacionado con scope? Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de traer solo los POST sin comentarios y si es que tienen comentarios solo me traigan si el último comentario es contact_type_id=4 , el tema logro hacer que me traiga el listado de productos con o sin comentarios, pero no logro hacer que me haga tambien el filtro que si el último comentario es con ID 4 me lo muestre, por lo que opta por traerme todo el dato.

¿Como podría solucionarlo? ya que depsues de esa conulta hago mas scope que filtran mas cosas del Producto.

**Controller**

```
$leads = Lead::openedStage1()->doesntCommentOrHasComments($filter_id);
```

**Model**

```
public function scopeOpenedStage1($query){
    $query
        ->where('status_id','!=',5)->where('status_id','!=',4);
}

public function scopeDoesntCommentOrHasComments($query,$filter_id){
        if ($filter_id == 1 )
            $query->doesntHave('comments')->orWhereHas('comments', function($q){
                $q->where('contact_type_id','=',4)->orderBy('date_publication','DESC');//not worked latest
            });

        if ($filter_id == 2)
            $query->doesntHave('comments')->orWhereHas('comments', function ($q){
                $q->where('contact_type_id','!=',4);
            });
            
        return $query;
    }
```

Adjunto a continuación las tablas. La tabla grande sería Products y la tabla pequeña seria COMMENTS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es un ID que te dice si es ```GESTION AUTOMATICA, USUARIO, VENDEDOR``` el que deja le comentario. Ya que quiero que me muestre el producto si es que no tiene comentarios y en caso que tenga comentarios solo permita visualizar el producto siempre y cuando el último comentario registrado sea ID 4

Comment: por ejemplo ```Galaxy S21, product_id = X / contact_type_id = 4 /comment = 'No registra el pago por transbank" / date_publication 2021-04-01 16:03``` Entonces con ese ejemplo deberia mostrarmelo, pero si despues de ese comentario se registraotro con distinto CONTACT_TYPE_ID desaparecera de la vista

Comment: Si existe en la tabla

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ funciona, yo cabeceandome 7 horas en tratar de hacerlo bueno igual no sabia como hacer la subconsulta dentro del scope y crei que no se podía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para responder voy a tomar esta parte de tu pregunta, ya que después se confunde un poco cuando muestras la estructura de la tablas en BD, que tienen nombres no convencionales:

> Estoy tratando de traer solo los POST sin comentarios y si es que tienen comentarios solo me traigan si el último comentario es `contact_type_id = 4`.

Comienzas la consulta desde el modelo Post:

```
Post::doesntCommentOrHasComments($filter_id);
```

Ya tienes resuelto *"traer solo los POST sin comentarios"* [consultando la ausencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```
$query->doesntHave('comments')
```

Y también ya tienes planteado resolver *"Y si es que tienen comentarios solo me traigan si el último comentario es `contact_type_id=4`"* [consultando la existencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), con un `orWhereHas` para definir restricciones de consulta adicionales:

```
$query->orWhereHas('comments', function($q) {
    // aquí hacer una cláusula que devuelva un comentario, 
    // sólo si es el último y en la columna contact_type_id tiene valor 4.

    // si devuelve alguno, le va a decir al whereHas que sí, 
    // que tiene un comentario como el de la cláusula.
});
```

La solución que propongo, es usando una [Subconsulta en una cláusula Where](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses),  inspeccionando el contenido de los comentarios.

Entonces vamos a suponer que tienes una tabla `posts` y otra tabla `comments`.

En la tabla `comments` están la columna `post_id` (que la relaciona con la column `id` de la tabla `posts`) y la columna `contact_type_id` que es la que va a condicionar la consulta.

Esta cláusula `where` recibe 2 parámetros, una función con la subconsulta y el valor a comparar.

```
$contact_type_id = 4;
$que->where(function ($que) { $subconsulta; }, $contact_type_id);
```

La subconsulta puede ser algo así:

```
$subconsulta =  $que->select('contact_type_id')
                    ->from('comments') 
                    ->whereColumn('comments.post_id', 'posts.id')
                    ->orderByDesc('comments.date_publication')
                    ->limit(1);
```

En detalle:

selecciona cuál es la columna que tiene el valor que te interesa

```
->select('contact_type_id')
```

de la tabla comments

```
->from('comments') // OJO, es el nombre de la tabla, no confundir con el nombre de la relación.
```

sólo las filas de la tabla comments que pertenezcan al Post correspondiente

```
->whereColumn('comments.post_id', 'posts.id')
```

lo ordena de manera que el último quede primero

```
->orderByDesc('comments.date_publication')
```

y toma sólo uno

```
->limit(1);
```

Finalmente, en tu scope sería algo así:

```
public function scopeDoesntCommentOrHasComments($query, $filter_id)
{
    if ($filter_id == 1 )
        $query->doesntHave('comments')
            ->orWhereHas('comments', function($q) {
                $q->where(function ($que) {
                    $que->select('contact_type_id')
                        ->from('comments')
                        ->whereColumn('comments.post_id', 'posts.id') 
                        ->orderByDesc('comments.date_publication')
                        ->limit(1);
                }, 4);
            });

    //...
        
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pensaría que con una consulta como esta lo resolverías:

```
public function scopeFiltraPosts($query) 
{
    $evaluaSiTieneComentarios = Post::has('comments')->get();

    if ($evaluaSiTieneComentarios->isEmpty()) {
        return $query->get();
    }
    return $query->whereHas('comments', function ($consulta) {
        $consulta->whereContactTypeId(4)
            ->latest();
    })->get();
}
```

Lo que hice fue:

- Mantener la existencia del *query scope*
- Obtengo y asigno en una variable los posts obteniendo únicamente aquellos que si tienen al menos un comentario relacionado
- Mediante un condicional evalúo lo siguiente:

  - Si la colección esta vacía, entonces únicamente retorno de vuelta todos los posts
  - En caso contrario retorno los posts que si tienen comentarios, pero...

    - De los comentarios filtro indicando que tome solo aquellos cuyo `contact_type_id` sea igual a 4
    - Ordeno de manera descendente los que cumplan la condición anterior

Posterior para usar esta query debería alcanzar con:

```
Modelo::filtraPosts();
```

**Propuesta no. 2**

Ahora la consulta anterior puede tener el detalle de que si `$evaluaSiTieneComentarios` resulta ser una colección no vacía, entonces el retorno de valores serán solo los posts que si tienen comentarios filtrados por una condición dada pero ignorando aquellos que no poseen alguno vinculado

(*Hago la aclaración anterior debido a que inicialmente así había comprendido la pregunta*)

```
$postsSinComentarios = Post::doesntHave('comments')->get();

$postsConComentariosConFiltroParticular = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
                                                    $query->whereContactTypeId(4)
                                                        ->latest();
                                                })->get();

$postsSinComentarios->merge($postsConComentariosConFiltroParticular);
```

Donde:

- Obtenemos una colección de todos los posts que **no tienen** al menos un comentario asociado y lo asignamos en una variable
- En una nueva variable asignamos una colección que obtenga todos los posts que tienen al menos un comentario hecho y que dicho comentario cumpla una condición
- Finalmente hacemos un *merge* de ambas colecciones

Lectura de referencia:

- [*Querying relationship existence*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Aqui *En caso contrario retorno los posts con sus comentarios, pero.* una acotación debería ser: *retorno los posts que si tienen comentarios*

Comment: Por lo que entendí de la pregunta, debiera devolver un mix de aquellos sin comentarios + aquellos con comentarios de tipo 4. Tu solución no muestra aquellos sin comentarios a menos que ninguno los tenga en toda la colección

Comment: Vaya, me hace sentido (*aunque si te doy honesto yo lo había entendido del modo en que respondí, pero gracias más tarde edito*)